# How to compare two arrays in React and change className if something appears in both arrays?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I want to compare if a 'track id' appears in both the 'search results' list and the 'playlist list', and change the class name if so.

The following is the function I have written to do so:

```
onDuplicate() {
if (this.state.searchResults.filter(track => this.state.playlistTracks.includes(track.id))) {
  return "Track-information-added";
} else {
  return "Track-information";
}
```

}

I then passed this down as a prop to the desired component and called it in the className attribute like so:

```
alreadyAdded() {
   this.props.onDuplicate();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="Track">
            <div className={this.alreadyAdded}>
```

I then applied different CSS styles to the two class names, but nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

Call the function inside the className like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [{id: 1}],
      playlistTracks: [1],
    }
  }

  onDuplicate() {
    const {searchResults,playlistTracks} = this.state

    if (searchResults.filter(track => playlistTracks.includes(track.id))) {
      return "Track-information-added";
    } else {
      return "Track-information";
    }
  }
  alreadyAdded() {
    return this.onDuplicate()
  }
  render() {
    return <div className={this.alreadyAdded()}>Duplicates</div>;
  }
}

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

working link for your code: https://codepen.io/ak2403/pen/YzVKzNY

Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function `alreadyAdded` and return the result in this function:

```
alreadyAdded() {
  return this.props.onDuplicate();
}
...
<div className = {this.alreadyAdded()}>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the return in your second function although the first one does return a value the second one does nothing with it .

```
               alreadyAdded() {

                         return this.props.onDuplicate();

                        }
```

or just call the first function directly this.porps.onDuplicate()